# Laravel TokenMismatchException in Ajax while using token

Tags: laravel-5

I know that I'am beginner at StackOverflow but I'am facing a hard problem.
Okay, going down to business I have troubles with token in laravel. Sometimes everything goes well but I have error:
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/checkabsence/delete 500 (Internal Server Error)

My js: 
     `$.ajax({
              method:"post",
              url:postDeleteAbsence,
              data:{
                _token:token,
                absenceid: absenceid
              }
              }).done(function(msg) {
                alert('deleted');
              });`

I'am 100% sure that I am passing the token and absenceid. My token is set in my view:    `var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';`

My Route:

```
Route::post('/checkabsence/delete', [
'uses' => 'AbsenceController@postDeleteAbsence',
'as' => 'postDeleteAbsence',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

My controller:

```
public function postDeleteAbsence(Request $request) {
   //code
}
```

My version of laravel: **5.2.41**

In my last project I've created multiple Ajax requests and everything worked very well and now I got this error...
Note that sometimes I got also token mismatch on non-ajax post request (for example on fifth request it throws token mismatch error)

I hope that you'll help me, because I really don't know what to do or what I am doing wrong...

//News
I've noticed that token which I have in my database differs from the token which I use in my ajax request and in other places.

Routes:
[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igict.png)

Comment: try `{{csrf_token()}}` instead of `{{ Session::token() }}`

Comment: I've tried, nothing changes :(

Comment: is it like it works first time and then it don't ?

Comment: No it's not working at any time. Always throws the same error Internal server error 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you have. In my case the reason was the authentication while user login. I was using `Auth::login($user, true);` instead of using `Auth::login($user);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the token as a header when using AJAX.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': {{ csrf_token() }}
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Try to add the token this way:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: postDeleteAbsence,
    data: {
        absenceid: absenceid
    },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>'
    }
}).done(function(msg) {
    alert('deleted');
});
```

Comment: Tried that solution, still the same problem.

Comment: But can you tell me it's that ok that the remember_token in database differs from currently showed token which I log in my console?

Comment: @mrforexify *remember_token* is a totally different thing from this tiken. This is for CSRF protection of the request, and the other one is for the user login session.

Comment: So which exactly should I use in ajax requests and for example in login form?

Comment: @mrforexify on every form you should use *csrf_token()*, remember_token is handled by the build in laravel authentication so you can forget about it.

Comment: Ok, I use it in every form but I still have the same error.

Comment: @mrforexify I added another way in my answer, check the edit and give it a try this way.

Comment: Changed and still the same issue, I really don't know what's wrong it's been 2 days and I am still facing the same problem :(

Comment: @mrforexify can you run `php artisan route:list` and add to the question just the middleware section of the route that you're trying to request.

Comment: Okay, I did that. Anyway isn't it weird that sometimes post routes work properly I mean that non-ajax post routes work properly and sometimes they throw token mismatch exception. Hmm

Comment: I'm seeing that get methods with ajax work very properly but I'm still getting errors with post methods.

Comment: @mrforexify I'm out of ideas, sorry. You'll have to debug this on your own. Open *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php* and inside the *tokensMatch()* method debug why the tokens don't match.